# Insert tables into group using Corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

How can I insert a table into a group?

I need to insert the following:

```
    local images = {
    "rowName.img[1]",
    "rowName.img[2]",
    }
```

into a group like this:

```
    group:insert(images)
```

Again, I know that group:insert doesn't work with tables. I tried using:

```
    group.images = images
```

but I don't know if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: What is content of images table, it doesn't really make sense, are the entries really strings or did you intend to store images in there? The soln will be different.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a for loop of your images array and insert them into the group one by one:

```
for i=1, #images do
    table.insert(group, images[i])
end
```

Comment: I think in line 2 you mean group:insert(images[i]) because he is asking to insert it in display group.